valgrind unhandled instruction bytes / Unrecognised instruction
I want to check my C++ application in valgrind as I get weird crashes on some machines, but not on my machine which I use for developing. But I cannot get anywhere. Right as the application starts up it errors out. I use Ubuntu 24.04. I run
valgrind --leak-check=full -s test

I get the output:
==45078== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==45078== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==45078== Using Valgrind-3.22.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==45078== Command: test
==45078== 
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0x62 0xF1 0xFD 0x48 0x7F 0x5 0x5A 0x9B 0x3F 0x0
vex amd64->IR:   REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=NONE
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
==45078== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x13e59c.
==45078==    at 0x13E59C: Wrapper (opencl.hpp:2073)
==45078==    by 0x13E59C: Context (opencl.hpp:3283)
==45078==    by 0x13E59C: Data (clFunctions.hpp:56)
==45078==    by 0x13E59C: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0() (clMain.cpp:31)
==45078==    by 0x96C5303: call_init (libc-start.c:145)
==45078==    by 0x96C5303: __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34 (libc-start.c:347)
==45078==    by 0x147244: (below main) (in /home/rainer/x/build)
==45078== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==45078== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==45078== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==45078==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==45078==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==45078== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==45078==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==45078==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==45078== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==45078== probably kill your program.
==45078== 
==45078== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==45078==  Illegal opcode at address 0x13E59C
==45078==    at 0x13E59C: Wrapper (opencl.hpp:2073)
==45078==    by 0x13E59C: Context (opencl.hpp:3283)
==45078==    by 0x13E59C: Data (clFunctions.hpp:56)
==45078==    by 0x13E59C: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0() (clMain.cpp:31)
==45078==    by 0x96C5303: call_init (libc-start.c:145)
==45078==    by 0x96C5303: __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34 (libc-start.c:347)
==45078==    by 0x147244: (below main) (in /home/rainer/x/build)
==45078== 
==45078== HEAP SUMMARY:
==45078==     in use at exit: 287,899 bytes in 2,009 blocks
==45078==   total heap usage: 3,543 allocs, 1,534 frees, 422,209 bytes allocated
==45078== 
==45078== 336 bytes in 7 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 292 of 330
==45078==    at 0x4846828: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==45078==    by 0x505B3AD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.555.42.06)
==45078==    by 0x506524C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.555.42.06)
==45078==    by 0x4CB9914: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.555.42.06)
==45078==    by 0x51404A1: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.555.42.06)
==45078==    by 0x4CB7012: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.555.42.06)
==45078==    by 0x4005823: call_init (dl-init.c:120)
==45078==    by 0x4005823: _dl_init (dl-init.c:121)
==45078==    by 0x401F59F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
==45078==    by 0x6: ???
==45078==    by 0x1FFF000026: ???
==45078==    by 0x1FFF000039: ???
==45078==    by 0x1FFF00003C: ???
==45078== 
==45078== LEAK SUMMARY:
==45078==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==45078==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==45078==      possibly lost: 336 bytes in 7 blocks
==45078==    still reachable: 285,547 bytes in 1,981 blocks
==45078==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==45078== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==45078== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==45078== 
==45078== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

My program contains OpenCL code, so looking at it:
clMain.cpp:31, that's where I declare a struct that contains cl::Context
going into opencl.hpp, the offending line then is
template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    typedef T cl_type;

protected:
    cl_type object_;

public:
    Wrapper() : object_(nullptr) { } //<---------------- line 2073
    
...

Now how is that Constructor of class Wrapper an Unrecognised instruction? I do not know what to make of this all?

Look at the disassembly/hex dump of the constructor. Do you see the bytes indicated in the valgrind message?

This looks like an AVX-512 instruction. From what I can tell valgrind doesn't yet support AVX-512: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383010

Also see: https://archive.fosdem.org/2022/schedule/event/valgrind_avx512/

There is indeed AVX-512 code in some source files, but I did not expect that to interfere at this point. I now removed everything AVX related and hopefully can make progress on the subject. But now I have more questions on how to deal with AVX code. I guess that is a new question

Generally if you get an unhandled instruction that means the leak results are meaningless. In most cases the result is a SIGILL and the exe terminates with a core dump. If your code has a signal handler for SIGILL that performs a cleanup then the leak results will be meaningful.

If you can build without AVX-512 then it should work.

I got what I wanted to. In the end the problem was I compiled too many source files with AVX512 enabled. Maybe as long as Valgrind does not fully understand AVX512 instructions, it could at least point that fact out, something like this appears to be an AVX512 instruction, which Valgrind can not handle at this point?

This is
0:  62 f1 fd 48 7f 55 a9    vmovdqa64 ZMMWORD PTR [rbp-0x15c0],zmm2
As said in the comments this is AVX512 which isn't supported.
This is the most requested feature in Valgrind, but we don't have anyone to work on it (and it's a big project).

Hi Paul.  Thank-you for your work on  Valgrind.  If Valgrind gives an Unrecognised instruction at address <address> error, but still continues running, does this invalidate the rest of the test?  I.e., can the final leak summary still be trusted?
